# PHP closure in other closure : scope of "use"

Tags: php, closures

I have a code that looks like this :

```
$app->add(function($req, $res, $next) {
    # closure A
    $res->on('end', function($res) use ($req) {
        # closure B
    });
    $next();
});
```

As you can see, I have a closure in a closure. Closure B is receiving `$res`ponse from the event so there's no problem with it. But it is also `use`ing `$req`uest from closure A.
Here, i have a doubt about the scoping of the `use`'d variable, I see two possibilities :

- Any response will have its own request object, because the closure B is re-created for each new listener passed to `$res->on`. So there's many closures B with their own scope inherited once from the used variable of closure A.
- Or: any new request will replace `$req` and `$res` in closure A (normal behaviour...) BUT will also replace the `$req` used by precedently-created closures B. And that would be problematic if a request #1 is not answered before a request #2 arrives (this is asynchronous code based on an event loop).

I hope I'm clear enough. I ask this because, for example, in JavaScript, we sometimes have to use callback generators to ensure that the scope of a sub-closure is not replaced.

---

**Edit:** I tried with a code that theoritically does the same thing, but which is easier to test:

```
$a = function($var) {
    return function() use ($var) {
        var_dump($var);
    };
};

$fn1 = $a((object) ['val' => 1]);
$fn2 = $a((object) ['val' => 2]);
$fn2();
$fn1();
```

The output (2, 1) showed that the first function `$fn1` has kept its original scope. Also, I noticed that the output of `var_dump` on a Closure object shows the scope it brings:

```
object(Closure)#3 (1) {
  ["static"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["res"]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
      ["val"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Technical explanation? I think that's because closures in PHP are regular PHP objects where `use` is a sort of constructor.

- Closures in the example just above are acting like this: http://pastebin.com/qkQ5GDFw
- But not like this, where I force PHP to keep the same reference, which is not possible with closure's "constructors": http://pastebin.com/ixfVh2Uf

Am I right? Any PHP specialist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, each `Closure` object in PHP contains a hash table. This table stores the values that are copied into the closure's scope with the `use` keyword. Arrays in PHP are also implemented using a hash table.

When you `use` a set of variables in a closure, it is as though you've created an array containing each variable being used. Each closure contains it's own unique "array" of values that is initialized when it is created. Unlike a normal array, the table of variables used in a closure cannot be modified.

```
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;

$closure = function () use ($var1, $var2) {
    return $var1 . ", " . $var2 . "\n";
};

$array = [$var1, $var2];

$var1 = 3;
$var2 = 4;

echo $closure(); // echoes 1, 2
echo $array[0] . ", " . $array[1] . "\n"; // echoes 1, 2
```

Changing the value of `$var1` will not affect the value at `$array[0]`, nor would it change the value of `$var1` within `$closure`.

When you use an object in a closure, that object may be changed outside of the closure and those changes will be reflected in the closure. Objects are not cloned when used in a closure. However, because you cannot modify the variable itself, you cannot change the variable to point at a different object.

Variables may also be used in a closure by reference. This allows a variable value to be modified outside of a closure and those changes to be reflected within the closure itself.

```
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;

$closure = function () use (&$var1, $var2) {
    return $var1 . ", " . $var2 . "\n";
};

$array = [&$var1, $var2];

$var1 = 3;
$var2 = 4;

echo $closure(); // echoes 3, 2
echo $array[0] . ", " . $array[1] . "\n"; // echoes 3, 2
```

When the closure above is created, a reference to `$var1` is created in the closure's table of values, but only the value of `$var2` is copied into the table. When the values of `$var1` and `$var2` were changed, only the value of `$var1` was changed within the closure because only that variable was used by reference. This again is similar to creating an array where `$var1` is added to the array by reference, but the value of `$var2` is copied to the array.

When a closure is created within a closure, the internal closure is copying the value of the variables at the time the closure is created. It does not matter that it is being created within another closure.

```
$value = 1;

$closure = function ($arg) use ($value) {
    return function () use ($arg, $value) {
        return $value + $arg;
    };
};

$value = 10;

$callback1 = $closure(1);
$callback2 = $closure(2);

echo $callback1() . "\n"; // Echoes 2
echo $callback2() . "\n"; // Echoes 3
```

**TL;DR:** The value of a variable is *copied* into a closure when the closure is created. To be able to modify the value outside of the closure, the value must be used by reference (e.g., `function () use (&$value) { ... }`).

Comment: I don't know why I've never accepted that answer but it helped a lot at the time to understand PHP's internals. Thanks =)